# Display issues LWJGL

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I am running this simple code to display a window in eclipse using lwjgl:

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class DisplayExample {

public void start() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1920, 1080));
        Display.create();




    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // init OpenGL here

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

        // render OpenGL here

        Display.update(); //flushes OpenGL pipeline and swaps back and front buffers. perhaps waits for v-sync.
    }

    Display.destroy();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    DisplayExample displayExample = new DisplayExample();
    displayExample.start();
}
}
```

However the screen appears like this and is flickering:
http://tinypic.com/r/33upp2u/6
This is running on a mac, any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't clearing the screen before you update the display. Add `GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` before `// render OpenGL here`. You also need to import the `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11` class for this.